# AWS DynamoDB not inserting all items from IoT Core with Rules engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, rules, aws-iot-core

So I have a problem with an IoT solution I have created using AWS IoT Core, AWS Rules Engine and AWS DynamoDB.

The solution looks like the following: MQTT messages are published to a topic "topic/+/data" where
the "+" is the thing that is publishing a message. There is a rule that intercepts these messages
and is supposed to save the published message as a record in a DynamoDB table. The problem is that
not all messages are persisted in the database. The DynamoDB tables capacity mode is set to be "On-demand".

Possible things that can have gone wrong:

1. Not all messages are published to the topic stream
2. The rule doesn't catch all messages
3. DynamoDB isn't persisting all messages as it should

1 and 2 can be eliminated since AWS Cloudwatch IoT logs only shows successful "RuleExecution" events that correspond to the amount of messages published i.e if there was 600 messages published
then there was 600 successful "RuleExecution" events. This was also tested for 500 messages published. The messages originated from a load test by Apache JMeter where different numbers of devices where simulated to post a message each second. The number of devices ranged from 10 to 100 and ran between 30 seconds and 15 minutes. All tests resulted in a large percentage, up to 30%, of
messages that were not inserted in to the DynamoDB table even though Cloudwatch claims that they were successful insertions.

Somehow DynamoDB doesn't insert all the messages that are intercepted byt the rule even though
Cloudwatch confirms that all the "RuleExecution" events are successful. Cloudwatch does not present any failed events either.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: How are you determining that not all items made it into DynamoDB? Is there any chance that multiple items have the same keys (hence one overwrites a previous item)?

Comment: @jarmod This went totaly over my head when creating the solution. This sound like a very likely cause, since the primary key used for each table entry is the  unix timestamp. With 100 queued entries each second, some might end up having the same key. Since the timestamp() function in AWS IoT Rules operates on milliseconds there is probably going to be some overwrites once the inserts/second increases. But an overwrite rate of 30% when there are 100 messages posted to the topic stream each second seems unlikely. Although I appreciate the thought.

Comment: You can count the number of puts to DynamoDB either explicitly in your code or via CloudTrail, then compare to the count of items in your table. That will quickly alert you to duplicate keys. Or you could modify your put to make it conditional upon an item with that key not existing, by using a [condition](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-condition-expressions/#1-confirming-existence-or-non-existence-of-an-item) and raise a visible error.

Comment: Although, since the messages originate from a JMeter script that runs all the threads simultaneously and there is a 1 second delay for each thread to make a post, meaning that all the threads try to post at the same time, this could be the cause.

Comment: If viable, you could append a short UUID suffix to the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collisions of the primary key were the problem. By using the `timestamp()` as the primary key and the `traceid()` as the sort key, everything works as intended. I can see now in the table that several entries have the same timestamp.

To be clear: The rule used to insert messages in to DynamoDB (The IAM role is cropped out):

[image]